# Поведение сравнения типов в PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое происходит?

```
<?php 
var_dump(0 == 'no');

>bool(true)`
```

[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/GLxCBg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что так и должно быть. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php).

Если очень коротко - строка преобразовывается в целое, а в данном случае это  будет 0.